# Which HTML element was Double Clicked in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I would like to detect which HTML element was double clicked. Seems to something not fire in my code. Following is my HTML code structure where you double click detect which item is clicked.

```
  <div id="mainWrapper">
       <div id="Banner" name="Banner" class="editable">This is the banner</div>
       <div id="MainMenu" class="editable">This is the main menu</div>
       <div id="LeftSideBar" class="editable">This is the submenu or left sidebar content</div>
       <div id="MainContent"class="editable">Here is the main content</div>
       <div id="RightSideBar" class="editable">Here are commercial ads</div>
       <div id="Footer"class="editable">This is the footer
          <a href="index.php">Go Home</a>
       </div>
  </div>
```

External JavaScript

```
window.onload = function(){
  // Listen to the double click event.
  if ( window.addEventListener )
     document.body.addEventListener( 'dblclick', onDoubleClick, false );
}
```

Get the element which fired the event. This is not necessarily the element to which the event has been attached.

```
function onDoubleClick( ev ){
  var element = ev.target || ev.srcElement;  //target = W3C,  srcElement = Microsoft
  alert(ev.type); //displays which event has fired

  var targ;
  if (!ev) var e = window.event;
  if (ev.target) targ = ev.target;  
  else if (ev.srcElement) targ = ev.srcElement;

  alert(ev.target); //displays which type of html element has been clicked (it shows div but not which div)

  // Find out the div that holds this element.
  var name;
  do {
    element = element.parentNode;
  }
  while ( element && ( name = element.nodeName.toLowerCase() ) && ( name != 'div' || 

  element.className.indexOf( 'editable' ) == -1 ) && name != 'body' )

  alert("The class name for the element is " + element.className); // I get nothing
  alert("The node name for the html element is " + element.nodeName);// I get "body"
}
```

Comment: You are attaching event handler to DOM, do you want to do it for a specific element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish. Is it so people can edit things? I'd be tempted to apply the onclick event listener just to those items you want to be editable. If they all have "editable" css classes, doing so is trivial with jquery:

```
$('.editable').dblclick(dblclickFunc)
```

This would apply an event listener to every element with a class of editable. However, to make it more useful, I'd change that to

```
$('.editable').dblclick(function(e){ dblclickFunc(e, this);  })
```

and for the function

```
dblclickFunc(e, el){
     alert('received an event of type ' + e.type + ' on ' + el.tagName);
}
```

So you've got a reference to the element that sent the event. From there, you could check IDs, or even go so far as to loop through all your editable elements and compare them to the one that got passed to you. Once you have a match, you know precisely which element was clicked on.

Comment: Why add multiple listeners instead of a single event delegation to the document like the poster already did? What would that solve? Event delegation seems much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You are using JavaScript in your example, but you also tagged the question with jQuery, so I assume jQuery is OK to use. In fact, exactly this type of event handling is greatly simplified using jQuery’s API, since it normalizes the events for all modern browsers. Highly recommended.

You can delegate the event to the `document` and detect all double clicks in the entire document using jQuery using the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$(document).on('dblclick', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target); // target is the element that triggered the event
    alert("The class name for the element is " + e.target.className);
    alert("The node name for the html element is " + e.target.nodeName);
});
```

If you want to listen on certain elements inside a specific container, try this:

```
$('#mainwrapper').on('dblclick', 'div', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

This will listen for any double clicks inside `#mainwrapper`, but only trigger the handler if a `DIV` element was the target.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.on()`

```
 $(".editable").on("dblclick", function(e){

     $(this).attr('class') //Class Name

 });
```

Comment: `live()` is deprecated, use `on()` instead.